# Queuing Biztalk Subscriptions

Tags: biztalk

We have a system sending HL7 messages to BizTalk using the MLLP HL7 accelerator.  We then have several destination systems, which all need their own format of the HL7 message, so we use orchestrations for each destination, each involving a different transform.  Each orchestrationi uses a filter to subscribe to the receive port.  This subscription model works fairly well, but what if we need to stop or undeploy one of the orchestrations.  The drawback of the subscription model, over a push model is that there is no queuing built in, so if the orchestration is removed, the messages picked up by the receive port do not queue for that system.  Or is this a concern?  How do you handle upgrades to the orchestration, etc.  Is there a better design pattern?

Answer (score 4):

A slightly better design in my opinion is to place the transformations (maps) directly on the send ports. You can then have your filters on the different send ports to route to the destinations systems.

This design would make updates a bit easier as there isn't a orchestration that first needs to be removed to deploy a new version of the map. All you then have to do is to stop the port ( that leaves the subscription active and messages will be queued for its subscribing ports). After the port is stopped you can just modify the resource (assembly) with the new version of the map and then start to port to start transforming and sending the queued messages.

It's usally a good idea to ***only*** use orchestration when you need to controll a more complex workflow - not just to apply a map as in you case.

Comment: +1. Good advice, and could work in the bulk of our scenarios.  In some of our more complex projects where an orchestration is still required, do you know of design patterns I can employe to mitigate the situation I described?

Comment: Since you can have multiple subscribers to a message, you can use send ports with outbound maps on them with a filter expression. You can use filters on send ports in tandem with your filtered orchestrations. When you stop an orchestration (and keep it enlisted), it'll still queue up messages, that way you don't lose anything and it'll process what's queued up after you restart it.